# Php error that shouldn't be happening with mysqli

Tags: php, select, mysqli

Why am I getting this in my php error results? I have labeled the line where the error is occurring. Call to a member function query() on a non-object.

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hotname_Database;dbname=$database_Database", $username_Database, $password_Database);

  $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT ida FROM finisheddatabase ORDER BY ida DESC LIMIT 1");   //getting error here
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);


$sql = "INSERT INTO finito(hadd, fisa) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$q = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$params = array( $tott, {$row['idz']} );
$q->execute( $params );
```

Comment: `$mysqli` is not a mysqli object. Is it _in scope_?

Comment: what comes before this, did you create your $mysqli connection properly?  start here http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

Comment: Yes. Without this, the script works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change those lines

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT ida FROM finisheddatabase ORDER BY ida DESC LIMIT 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
```

to

```
$sql=$dbh->prepare("SELECT ida FROM finisheddatabase ORDER BY ida DESC LIMIT 1");
$row = $dbh->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ;
print_r($row->fetchAll());
```

Comment: Wow. It was as simple as using PDO instead of mysqli. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing access to the mysqli interface: The first line uses the object interface, the second line used the function interface. Don't mix.